# how to set information on a thread context using ASM?

Tags: bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

Each time a new thread is being created / picked out of a threadpool, I want to be able to set some context information about it.

I'll appreciate for guidelines about what is the best approach to do it using ASM.

Thanks,
Nadav

Comment: You have to be more specific about the “picked out of a threadpool” part. That’s a logical operation whose actual implementation may spread over several methods and classes whose semantic might not be obvious to a byte code processing software.

Comment: Basically what I want is that each time a user schedule a work to be done, I'll be able to pass some metadata to thread which executes it. I want to have a transaction id which starts at some point during runtime, and then I want pass it to any new thread so I'll be able to see that it took part in that particular transaction.

Answer (score 0):

This requires you to instrument the methods that start a thread or that is traversed when a thread pool triggers a new task. This makes this straigt forward:

1. You can instrument the `Thread::start` method for setting such a value for a `Thread`.
2. You can instrument the `ThreadPoolExecutor::beforeExecute` method to set a `Thread` state for a `ThreadPoolExecutor`. It is not possible to do this for generic `Executor`s as they do not necessarily need to be backed by a `Thread`.

Comment: I assume that instrumenting these classes requires a redefinition of the classes?

Comment: Yes, it does. Those classes are used by the VM itself such that they are loaded when your agent is executed.

Comment: @nadavy: if you create a subclass of `ThreadPoolExecutor`, you can simply override `beforeExecute` as intended. Perhaps, you can avoid byte code instrumentation by designing the application appropriately in the first place.

Comment: Another issue which may be a bit more challenging is to pass the context between threads. For example, *thread-a* puts a message in a queue and *thread-b* reads from it. In this case, I want to thread-a will pass the context information to *thread-b*. Any thoughts about it?

Comment: In this case you would need to instrument / override both the method putting the task and the method that starts executing the task. In the end, instrumentation only allows you to do things that you could also program out if you changed the source code.

Comment: Of course, basically I hope to find the most general case in order to implement it in the best way.